# Holding event fired twice windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, ui-thread, eventhandler, messagedialog

I have a holding event on a `ListBoxItem`. So When I hold an item, it enters right in the function but it appears as it's fired twice.

```
private async void OutersAndContactInTel_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
        if (element.DataContext != null && element.DataContext is Contact)
        {
            Contact selectedContact = (ImOutContact)element.DataContext;
            if (selectedContact.IsOuter)
            {
                MessageDialog msgToAddContact = new MessageDialog("Voulez-vous vraiment suivre " + selectedContact.Pseudo + " ?");
                msgToAddContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Oui", (UICommandInvokedHandler) =>
                {
                    AddContactProcess(selectedContact);
                }));
                msgToAddContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Non"));

                this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => msgToAddContact.ShowAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog msgToInviteContact = new MessageDialog("Envoyez une invitation à  l'utilisation de l'application par sms à " + selectedContact.NomPrenom + " ?");
                msgToInviteContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Oui", (UICommandInvokedHandler) =>
                {
                    SendSmsToInvite(selectedContact);
                }));
                msgToInviteContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Non"));
                await msgToInviteContact.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog errorMessage = new MessageDialog(CustomDialogMessage.getMessageContent(CustomDialogMessage.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => errorMessage.ShowAsync());
    }
}
```

As I'm displaying a `MessageDialog` **msgToAddContact** at the end of that function, the fact that it's fired twice, it makes the `MessageDialog` displayed twice too.

If the first `MessageBox.showAsync` is not finished, it crashes because it's not possible to show multiple `MessageDialog` at the same time.

Does anyone knows how to block the second execution of the holding event?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just edited the post :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not awaiting on `Dispatcher.RunAsync`?

Comment: No there is no reason... When I was testing I removed it's to see the behavior but it the same issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just found out why it's firing more than one time. Events like Holding or SelectionChanged are events with different states. In my case, The holding event has 3 states: **started**, **completed**, **cancelled**. The different states are proceeding as follow. 
When I hold an element one time, the state of the event is **started**, when the whole function inside the eventHandler is done, the Holding Event is fired a second time with a state of **completed**, same thing if the user cancels the event.

Msft explains it well here: [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding)

To avoid executing the same code at each state, just add a condition at the beginning of the critical code which is to be executed just one time.

My code is actually looking that as you can compare with my firts post:

```
private async void OutersAndContactInTel_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
        if (element.DataContext != null && element.DataContext is Contact && e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started)
        {
            Contact selectedContact = (ImOutContact)element.DataContext;
            if (selectedContact.IsOuter)
            {
                MessageDialog msgToAddContact = new MessageDialog("Voulez-vous vraiment suivre " + selectedContact.Pseudo + " ?");
                msgToAddContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Oui", (UICommandInvokedHandler) =>
                {
                    AddContactProcess(selectedContact);
                }));
                msgToAddContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Non"));

                this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => msgToAddContact.ShowAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog msgToInviteContact = new MessageDialog("Envoyez une invitation à  l'utilisation de l'application par sms à " + selectedContact.NomPrenom + " ?");
                msgToInviteContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Oui", (UICommandInvokedHandler) =>
                {
                    SendSmsToInvite(selectedContact);
                }));
                msgToInviteContact.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Non"));
                await msgToInviteContact.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog errorMessage = new MessageDialog(CustomDialogMessage.getMessageContent(CustomDialogMessage.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => errorMessage.ShowAsync());
    }
}
```